# Why are there few compilers that comply with C99?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, c99

It's over ten years since C99 was published. However, so far there have been few, if any, compilers that have support for all the new features of C99. Why?

BTW: Are there really any compilers that fully comply with C99?

Comment: IME, most of the major C compilers support most of C99. It's just Microsoft that refuses to support it.

Comment: Full support is very hard to find.  C11 might have better luck, it deprecated some controversial C99 features from mandatory to optional.  Although you'd have to wonder what the point of an optional feature in a language standard might be, still nothing you can count on when portability is important.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia: C99 Implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#Implementations), Most popular compilers (except Visual Studio) have support for most but not all C99 features(like gcc or clang), but, yes, some compilers have already fully comply with C99.

I think one of the reasons is that some of the C99 features are not useful to some compiler vendors. The newest standard, C11, on the other hand, allows implementations to not support certain parts of the standard — including some that had been mandatory to support in C99, like complex types and variable length arrays. (See C11 §6.10.8.3 *Conditional feature macros*)

Comment: This is certainly not a question of "hard to implement". Some compiler vendors (notably microsoft) simply don't want it for political reasons.

Comment: @JensGustedt I modified my words, when talking aoubt C99, I ignored Micorsoft by default. By the way, it seems that Micosoft **finally** decided to add some C99 features to Visual Studio 2013. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/c-11-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> BTW: Are there really any compilers that fully comply with C99?

The two major public domain compilers clang and gcc are as far as one can get. There maybe some small issues that remain in the C library, but the C library is usually a different project from the compilers.

clang has C99 as its default and is moving relatively quickly towards C11.

gcc with flag `-std=c99` is compliant for any practical purposes.

Comment: Doesn't Intel support C99 as well?

Comment: Both HP and IBM claim full support, iirc.